# Bash add at the end of the line not working

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a bash script that adds " at the end of some lines. In order to do this, I used `sed 's/$/"/g'`, however, at most of the lines, it prints it at start of the line, replacing the first character. Example:

```
a
silly 
example    =>>>

"
"illy
example"
```

Comment: That means you have DOS line ending in your file. Convert your file to Linux file first.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior means you have DOS line ending in your file. You should convert your file to Linux file first.

In case you cannot do that, here is an alternate `sed` solution that takes into consideration presence of an optional `\r` (carriage return) before line break:

```
sed -E $'s/\r?$/"&/g' file
```